# I have a problem with inject Mock and Mock : Mockito with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito

Good morning,

I want to test a service: company.
However I have a problem.
When I want to perform a test by retrieving a user from my sql file, I get an error on this user.
However, when I put in @Mock annotation this service, the test passes.
However, I have to put this service in @InjectMocks.

Could you please help me ?

```
public class CompanyServiceUnitTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CompanyService companyService;
    @Mock
    private UserCompanyService userCompanyService;
    @Mock
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

@Test
    public void checkUserCompanyServiceNotCalled_WhenuserListEmpty()
            throws BadRequestException, ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user2 = new User();
        user2.setId(3);
        List<User> listUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        CompanyForm companyForm = new CompanyForm();
        companyForm.setName("ekeepit");
        companyForm.setCity("Lille");
        companyForm.setContact("Ekeep");
        companyForm.setEmail("ekeepit@ekeepit.com");
        companyForm.setPhone("0303034343");
        companyForm.setUsers(listUsers);

        Company company1 = companyService.addCompany(companyForm, user2);

        verifyNoInteractions(userCompanyService);
    }
```

and addCompany method:

```
    public Company addCompany(final CompanyForm companyForm, final User organisationOwner)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException, BadRequestException {

        if (companyForm == null || organisationOwner == null) {
            log.error("CompanyForm and OrganisationOwner can not be null");
            throw new BadRequestException("CompanyForm and OrganisationOwner can not be null");
        } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(companyForm.getName()) || StringUtils.isEmpty(companyForm.getContact())
                || StringUtils.isEmpty(companyForm.getEmail()) || StringUtils.isEmpty(companyForm.getPhone())
                || StringUtils.isEmpty(companyForm.getCity())) {
            log.error("All fields must be filled.");
            throw new BadRequestException("All fields must be filled.");
        } else if (!pattern.matcher(companyForm.getEmail()).matches()) {
            log.error("Email format is not valid.");
            throw new BadRequestException("Email format is not valid.");
        }
        Company company = Company.builder().createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .organization(this.organizationRepository.findOrganizationByOwner(organisationOwner)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(
                                "No organisation for the user " + organisationOwner.getId())))
                .name(companyForm.getName()).disable(false).city(companyForm.getCity())
                .contact(companyForm.getContact()).email(companyForm.getEmail()).phone(companyForm.getPhone()).build();
        companyRepository.save(company);

        if (Objects.nonNull(companyForm.getUsers())) {
            List<UserCompany> userCompanies = companyForm.getUsers().stream().map(user -> {
                UserCompany userCompany = new UserCompany();
                userCompany.setUser(user);
                userCompany.setCompany(company);
                userCompany.setDisable(false);
                return userCompany;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            this.userCompanyService.add(userCompanies);
        }
        return company;
```

Comment: You need to show the implementation of addCompany method

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @knittl , no organization for user 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your addCompany method calls organizationRepository.findOrganizationByOwner(...) so you need to mock the behaviour of this method

```
@Mock
private OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

// something like this
when(organizationRepository.findOrganizationByOwner(organisationOwner)).thenReturn(Optional.of(organisation));
```